# Tween Animation and Frame by Frame Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation, frame, tween

What is **Tween Animation** and **Frame by Frame Animation** in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tween animation can perform a series of simple transformations like

```
    position, size, rotation, and transparency
```

on the contents of a View object. So, if you have a TextView or ImageView object, you can move, rotate, grow, or shrink the text or image.

```
     While frame by frame animation do it on a set of images.
```

Answer (score 2):

Tween Animation: An animation that performs transitions such as rotating, fading, moving, and stretching on a graphic.

Frame by Frame Animation: An animation that shows a sequence of images in order (like a film).